# Not displayed checkboxes in bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap tabs and have a problem with forms when Names of Checkboxes are the same. Checkbox is not displayed in the other form. If to use  2 forms in the first tab everything goes well

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="ExportFSAClaims" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                tab1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="ExportFSABalances" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                tab2
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <form action="url1" method="POST">
                <input type="checkbox" name="IsTerminated" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <form action="url2" method="POST">
                <input type="checkbox" name="IsTerminated" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please create a bootply.com example and provide the link

Comment: Your code works good for me.

Comment: Both of the checkboxes are displayed. https://jsfiddle.net/bpm43mb7/ Probably you have something else that prevents displaying it.

Comment: Maybe it is relateted to mvc forms